# Not able to execute the .exe file generated from GCC compiler

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I am working on creating a system in C language and I have installed GCC compiler via MinGW Installer. After this, I created a basic Hello World program to check if the compiler is working properly. I compiled my code using the command `gcc hello.c -o hello` and then tried to run the executable file thus created by typing `hello` into the command prompt. But the system is not running my .exe file and giving an error - **The system cannot execute the specified program.**

I repeated the whole process on my second system, step by step, and I was able to see the output for the same program on the command prompt without any error.

I am not able to understand the exact reason behind this but I suspect it has something to do with the permission to execute a .exe file.

Comment: If you didn't have permissions to run executables, you'd not be able to do anything on your computer. So that's not it. One idea is that you're running a 32 bit operating system but are building a 64 bit executable. What is your exact version of Windows?

Comment: Do you need to type `./hello`?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I am using Windows 10 Home and it is a 64 bit operating system.

Comment: @FiddlingBits That is not the issue, I am able to do that on the other system.

Comment: Can it be something related to Virus and Threat Protection?

Comment: Well, that'd be for you to answer I think. How can we know what sort of antivirus or other pseudo-malware of that sort you're running... I've never had Windows prevent me from running most anything I'd build, but then I don't run any protection system other than what's included with Windows itself. And you certainly can disable the built-in antivirus if you think it's a problem. You don't need to ask our permission first :) But I'd suggest something rather simple first: [disable fast startup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) and power cycle your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `.exe` file with Dependancy Walker (https://www.dependencywalker.com/). It will tell you if there is something wrong with the file.

Also you should be able to see there if it's 32-bit or 64-bit. In case of 64-bit it won't run on your system if you're on a 32-bit Windows.

You could also try with MinGW-w64 built from http://winlibs.com/ (try the 32-bit version first) and follow the hello world instructions on that site.